Expected Time for Bus to Arrive based on Changing Probabilities?
Suppose there is a bus arrival with the following properties:

At schedule = 1, the bus is expected to arrive according to some random number generated from an exponential distribution with $\lambda$ = $\lambda_0$ minutes
For example, suppose this randomly generated number 7 minutes . Then, at time = 0 there is a p=0.5 probability that the bus arrives. At time =1 there is a p=0.5/2 probability that the bus arrives. At time=2, there is a p=0.5/3 probability that the bus arrives ... all the way to time=7.
If the bus does not arrive in 7 minutes, we go to schedule = 2.
In schedule 2, the bus is now expected to arrive in some random number generated from an exponential distribution with lambda=7. Again, we analyze the probability between each time interval t = 0,1 (p/2),2 (p/3),...
We repeat this process again and again until the bus finally arrives.

I tried to represent this process mathematically for the i-th schedule  given some initial lambda and p values (schedules start from 1 and time starts from 0).
The new lambda for the next schedule is generated from an exponential distribution centered around the previous lambda:
$$\lambda_{i+1} = \text{rexp}(1, \text{rate} = 1/\lambda_i)$$
Define $E_i$ as the expected arrival time for the i-th schedule:
$$
E_i = 
\begin{cases} 
\text{rexp}(1, \text{rate} = 1/\lambda_0) & \text{if } i = 1 \\
\text{rexp}(1, \text{rate} = 1/\lambda_{i-1}) & \text{if } i \neq 1 
\end{cases}
$$
Define $P_i(t)$ as the probability of the bus arriving at time t during the i-th schedule:
$$
P_i(t) = 
\begin{cases} 
p & \text{if } t = 0 \\
\frac{p}{t+1} & \text{if } t \neq 0 
\end{cases}
$$
Based on this, I have the following question:

Given some initial $\lambda_0$ and $p$, what is the expected schedule and time at which the bus will arrive at?
Suppose we started with some initial values $\lambda_0$ and $p$. Now, we are currently at the jth schedule and k-th time within the j-th schedule, and the bus has still not arrived (we dont know $\lambda_i$ at this point). Given this information, at what schedule and time is the bus expected to arrive?  (I think for this question we have to find out the expected lambda at the current time and schedule, and then propagate this number forward)

I wrote a computer simulation for this problem - but I was wondering if its possible to answer this question mathematically? (Note: I rounded all numbers to the nearest whole number)

$0.5$, $0.5/2$, $0.5/3$ is not an exponential distribution.

@ aschepler: within a given schedule, the probability reduces according to a fixed pattern (non-exponential)

Your example is not at all clear to me.
